# Unit Test against ActiveMQ

Tags: maven, unit-testing, activemq-classic

I use maven to run unit test. Every time i have to remember to start ActiveMQ first because the unit test need to send JMS message to Queue and consume it for assertion. I wonder is there some maven plugin to automatically launch the ActiveMQ for unit testing?

Is short. Is that possible to launch ActiveMQ before running unit testing.
I googled and found some tips. But according to that way. I should run a mvn command to launch the ActiveMQ which is not auto way to run unit test

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A shorthand to test AMQ flows from java is to connect to `vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false`.

That will create and start a new broker (if there is no one running). You will need no boiler plate code to create, configure and start/stop the broker.

However, that assumes you have no major configuration changes from the default values you want to test. In that case you may want to configure and start the broker manually.

You can do so by starting the broker in a `@Before` method in your Junit test.

i.e.

```
BrokerService broker;

@Before
public void setupAMQ(){

   broker = new BrokerService();
   TransportConnector connector = new TransportConnector();
   connector.setUri(new URI("tcp://localhost:61616"));
   broker.addConnector(connector);
   // More config here!
   broker.start()
}

@After
public void tearDownAMQ(){
   broker.stop();
}
```

[Read more about the topic](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-embed-a-broker-inside-a-connection.html).